# Tengo este problema al querer publicar mi primera app, para firmar le pongo la contraseña igual en las 4 partes

Tags: kotlin

[image: tengo ese error de la imagen]

Al momento de subir el aab me sale ese error en google play console.

Subiste un archivo APK o un Android App Bundle firmados con un certificado que aún no es válido. Debes firmarlos con un certificado que sea válido actualmente

Answer (score 0):

Al mostrarte este mensaje:

> Subiste un archivo APK o un Android App Bundle firmados con un
> certificado que aún no es válido. Debes firmarlos con un certificado
> **que sea válido actualmente**

Me parece que el problema en este caso es que la fecha del sistema que tiene tu computadora es incorrecta, revisa que la fecha y hora sea correcta. Lo que sucede es que cuando creaste tu certificado, este es válido, pero para una fecha que no coincide con la actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]